# Geolocation Redirect for Domain

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, nameserver

I'd like redirect users visiting the same domain to different domains based on their locations. So for example:

- European User -> Visits domain.com -> Forwarded to domain.eu
- US User -> Visits domain.com -> Forwarded to domain.us

But the thing is, I don't want to use htaccess or code redirect -- I'd like it to be a DNS level or Virtual Nameserver (if something like it exists?) redirect? Hope I'm making sense? It is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are geolocation patches for DNS servers (e.g. http://www.caraytech.com/geodns/).
But this would mean that domain.com would return different records for requests from different locations, you would still need to do the redirect from .com to .us somewhere.

But this you could do then already in the destination data center.

Comment: Hmm..what I'm looking to do is say I've set the NS for domain1.com to ns1 and ns2.host.com -- But internally, I want to set Nameservers eu.domain.com for europe and us.domain.com for EU and US users resp, and they should resolve to IPs. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use an HTTP level redirect - DNS on its own can't do this.

The only other way would be to use a content delivery network that can serve different content off the same domain name depending on the client's IP.

Comment: Yes, how do CDNs do it? So the concept of "Virtual Nameserver" does exist after all?

Comment: They look at the IP, use a geolocation service to determine its origin, then serve content depending upon the location. They don't use different domains, etc. at the DNS level.